# Why Tailwind css not work in vite+react project

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css, vite

I created a React application using Vite and used the documentation provided here to install Tailwind: [Tailwind CSS Installation Guide.](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite)

however still not working tailwind css in my react application.

**tailwind.config.js**

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
    content: [
        "./index.html",
        "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    ],
    theme: {
        extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [],

}
```

**postcss.config.js**

```
export default {
    plugins: {
        tailwindcss: {},
        autoprefixer: {},
    },
}
```

**vite.config.js**

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
})
```

**package.json**

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.6",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "eslint": "^8.44.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.26",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.3",
    "vite": "^4.4.0"
  }
```

**index.css**

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

but still not show this designs

**App.jsx**

```
function App() {

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className='head-text'>React App</h1>
      <p className="text-yellow-500">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus, quasi.</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: I don't see any problem here..... check if the src is properly defined or not according to your project `content: [
        "./index.html",
        "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    ],`

or else just move on to NextJs. NextJs by default include tailwind css

Comment: Check index.css is imported correctly or not?